# How to know if every queries executed successfully in loop?

Tags: c#, foreach, petapoco

Suppose I have executed an update query in loop using **PetaPoco** like,

```
foreach (var obj in mainObject) {
   db.Execute("update Table set Column = @0 where C1=@1 and C2 =@2", Column1, obj.data1, obj.data2);
}
```

How to know if each of these queries has been executed successfully ?

Comment: Why don't you save the returned values ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually [`PetaPoco`](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) returns **1** OR greater if a single query is executed successfully or means if any rows are affected and **0** if failed.

With this scenario you can trace those values by adding that in the loop, like:

```
List<int> checkSuccess = new List<int>(); //To trace the value returned by execute query

foreach (var obj in mainObject) {
    int updated = db.Execute("update Table set Column = @0 where C1=@1 and C2 =@2", Column1, obj.data1, obj.data2);
    checkSuccess.Add(updated);
}

if (checkSuccess.All(i => i >= 1))
{
    //Your every queries has been updated successfully
}
```

Comment: I was searching this for 2 days, Concept of List I thought but I was around near,  Thank you very much

Comment: Not quite correct, `Execute` doesn't return 1 for succeed and 0 for fail. It returns the number of affected rows. If you for example execute this query: `DELETE FROM Table` you'd delete all rows of this table and the return value would be the number of rows in this table. So it depends on the logic and the query if 0 is a fail or 1 is a succeed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ohh sorry, Thanks I really appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Another thanks for adding my mistake in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

[`Execute`](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/blob/0209ffd00aa04f0cb54122721a5b28578b7d50a1/PetaPoco/IExecute.cs) returns the number of affected rows. So if you update one row you'd get `1` as return value if it succeded, otherwise 0 (or an error).

```
bool allSucceeded = true;
foreach (var obj in mainObject) 
{
    int updated = db.Execute("update Table set Column = @0 where C1=@1 and C2 =@2", Column1, obj.data1, obj.data2);
    bool succeed = updated != 0;
    if(!succeed) 
        allSucceeded = false;
}
```

So `Execute` doesn't return 1 for succeed and 0 for fail. It returns the number of affected rows. If you for example execute this query: `DELETE FROM Table` you'd delete all rows of this table and the return value would be the number of rows in this table. So it depends on the logic and the query if 0 is a fail or 1 is a succeed.

By the way, this behaviour is consistent with ADO.NET methods like [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var obj in mainObject) 
{
    var result = db.Execute("update Table set Column = @0 where C1=@1 and C2 =@2", Column1, obj.data1, obj.data2);
    if (result < 1)
    {
     //not ok
    }
}
```